# Ninject 1.0 to 2.0 .Only

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, ninject

Hi I am following below link,
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/02/10/how-to-use-ninject-to-inject-dependencies-into-asp.net-mvc.aspx

I get error on line:

```
kernel.Bind<IHttpController>().To<MyTESTController>()
    .Only(When.Context.Variable("controllerName")
    .EqualTo("CorporateRequirementsController"))
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name == "ActionInvoker");
```

I believe `.Only` is the syntax from Ninject 1.0, what is the equivalent in 2.0?

The error I am getting is like this:

> 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<.../..../.Controllers.CorporateRequirementsController>' does not contain a definition for 'Only' and no extension method 'Only' accepting a first argument of type 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<.../..../.Controllers.CorporateRequirementsController>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: What error message do you got?

Comment: Updated the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Based from the old svn sources it was in 1.0 - http://ninject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Core/Binding/Syntax/IBindingConditionSyntax.cs , but at the current version it doesn't exist.

In the [their actual documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) there are a couple of samples on how you can do conditional binding: attributes\named bindings\when methods.

I suppose the closest to `Only` is

```
IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> When(Func<IRequest, bool> condition);
```

declared [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/e94cbaea5e86fe17a6a22b40a169fb09045a9449/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingWhenSyntax.cs) . So you can pass your custom function that will be called during object resolution and where you will check for controller type. There are also a couple of overloads of When method for different cases, so you may want to check them too.